# How does Microsoft.VisualBasic.Device.Network.Upload work?

Tags: c#, php, .net

I'm writing a DLL in C# and I'm making a reference to this VB assembly. After combing the internet I could not find how this function works on the server-side. How would you write a PHP script to receive the file uploaded by this function? Does it $_POST it or $_FILE it?

Edit: I followed Adnan's advice and var_dumped $_POST, $_FILE, $_REQUEST, and php://input. All come up with nothing useful. Even with a blank file, the name isn't coming through.

Here is the DLL's code for this function. I have a download function that works the same way.

```
public object UploadFile(string ToPath, string FromPath)
    {
        try
        {
            MyProject.Computer.Network.UploadFile(FromPath, ToPath);
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If I were you I'd just `var_dump($_REQUEST);var_dump($_FILE);` on the server script and see what I'd get. But hey it's just me, I know almost nothing about `.net`

Comment: Just saying that it didn't come up anything useful from dumping the files seems like bad idea. Add a dump to your post so others can examine it as well, they might spot something that you missed.

Comment: No... I'm serious. They were empty. ($_REQUEST had the get parameters in it, but thats it.) Either way, I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network.Uploadfile uses [WebClient.UploadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfileasync.aspx) internally with a POST-request (unless you specify a ftp-server as target address). Looking a bit deeper (using ILSpy) it seems to create a complete "multipart/form-data"-request (i.e. the same as if you put file upload in a html form) so it should be available in $_FILE (isn't it $_FILES?).

Comment: You are right, but I found another solution. Thanks for your help anyway!